# Are there any presto or trino connectors for Solr / SolrCloud?

Tags: solr, presto, solrj, solrcloud, trino

I need to run some scheduled ;SQL statements for SolrCloud programmatically in a dashboard joining several collections, the only option I found so far is by using Presto however I could not find any Solr connectors within Presto or Trino, so far I know that Solr has the JDBC/APIs available.

Note: I know there are some alternatives like ;
a) Moving the data from Solr to a supported store
b) Using python to query Solr SQL Handler interface via REST or use PySor
c) Using sqlalchemy dialect for solr in Superset : had some limitations with some schema definitions.
d) Spark-Solr: I need to avoid using Spark.
e) Thrift APIs : Not familiar with it.

But I need to use Pesto for its distributed nature and in-memory computations.